# reindent php language file to same => position

Tags: php, sublimetext3, indentation

Couldn't use my default php indent feature, how can I indent my php from this

```
<?php

return array(

  "txt.about" => "Tentang Tempat Ini",
  "txt.floor" => "Lantai",
  "txt.area" => "Area",
  "txt.size" => "Ukuran Space",
);
```

to this?

```
<?php

return array(

  "txt.about"  => "Tentang Tempat Ini",
  "txt.floor"  => "Lantai",
  "txt.area"   => "Area",
  "txt.size"   => "Ukuran Space",
);
```

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AlignTab

Answer (score 0):

The Tab key.  Functionally, the spaces make no difference whatsoever, so I wouldn't worry about it.